# Prevent jQuery on fire multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a web application which requires all data to be saved immediately.

I use the following lines to trigger the ajax call:

```
$('#form_global').on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    transaction_save();
});
```

My problem is that there are other events, which changes multiple inputs and the multiple input change triggers the ajax call multiple times.

Is there any way to prevent .on("change") to be fired multiple times?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the problem?  This code is going to execute any time that one element changes.  Doesn't the requirement dictate that you save those changes?

Comment: So, I have 1 select list and 10 input fields. When I change the selected, it changes 5 input fields. The .on("change") is fired 5 times, and the same data is saved 5 times. I would like to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

You can add below code after **e.preventDefault()**

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();

$('#form_global').on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    transaction_save();
});
```

Here's a [link](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)